# Should I unit test event handlers

Tags: .net, unit-testing

I tend to veer towards the opinion that only public interfaces should be tested, thereby covering testing of private procedures. However, an interesting question arose yesterday - should one test event handlers? My gut instinct is that logic should be stored in self-contained procedures invoked by the handlers themselves, but this is subjective and would more than likely result in private procedures rather than public ones that are being tested. Should I be unit testing event handlers and, if so, what are the best practices for doing so?

Answer (score 2):

In no way am I going to say someone is "wrong" for unit testing an event handler. Personally I'd go with the philosophy of "test what might break" and wouldn't.

The main thing I've seen consistently wrong with event code is something unit tests won't catch - the "On" method will just be:

```
if (MyEventHandler != null)
    MyEventHandler(this, e);
```

This has a race condition; MyEventHandler should be assigned to a variable before the null check.

The second common error is people passing null for the "e" event data parameter; this could be tested.

If you don't own a copy of Framework Design Guidelines 2nd Ed. by Cwalina & Abrams, buy it now. It will tell you how to write event code correctly every time, how to write the Dispose Pattern properly, and many other things.

Comment: That really go me thinking about what you are saying so I posted something that hopefully is complimentary to what you said, VERY good for calling this out friend, very good!

Answer (score 0):

I believe event handlers should be tested.  If you follow the normal pattern of doing something along the lines of:

```
public event EventHandler MyEvent;
protected void OnMyEvent()
{
    // Raise MyEvent here
}
```

Then testing of MyEvent is effectively part of the test of OnMyEvent, since the only "test" you will do is to verify that the event is raised properly.

Typically, testing an event means subscribing to it, and doing something that should (or should not) raise it.

Answer (score 0):

I read your question and didn't know if you were asking about the body of the handler or whether or not the handler was actually bound correctly to handle the event.

As you say, the body of the handler should simply call another method, which you've already tested (if it's public).

I generally don't unit test the wiring of event handlers unless they're going to be changing at runtime, as I'm very likely to catch in my developer and integration testing event handlers that don't bind/unbind at runtime, aren't wired up, and should have been.

Answer (score 0):

To TrueWill's point, here is a example of a good implementation of an event and its raise method. This is the `Click` event of the `Button` class from Microsoft. First note that they use a `EventHandlerList` to store the assignments in ...

```
protected EventHandlerList Events {
    get { 
        if (events == null) { 
            events = new EventHandlerList(this);
        } 
        return events;
    }
}

...

public event EventHandler Click {
    add {
        Events.AddHandler(EventClick, value); 
    }
    remove { 
        Events.RemoveHandler(EventClick, value); 
    }
}
```

Now take note to the actual raise method `OnClick`, it's probably much different than what you're used to seeing ...

```
protected virtual void OnClick(EventArgs e) { 
    Contract.Requires(e != null);
    EventHandler handler = (EventHandler)Events[EventClick]; 
    if (handler != null) handler(this, e); 
}
```

... don't worry about the line `Contract.Requires(e != null);`, that's their contract management framework, but notice it pulls it from the `EventHandlerList` and then if that handler isn't `null` they will fire it.

One other thing that's probably worth noting here is that you likely won't need to implement your events in quite the same manner, but the programming guide put out by Microsoft actually calls out the race condition in the second part of this guide that TrueWill is pointing out. You can find that guide [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx). This is actually one very good guide by Microsoft.

Now, **to your point**, I believe events should be tested and here is a mechanism I've used in the past ...

```
private ManualResetEvent _eventRaised = new ManualResetEvent(false);

[TestMethod]
public void TestSomething()
{
    _eventRaised.Reset();

    // hook up the event to the target being tested
    // NOW, in the event handler, issue _eventRaised.Set();

    // do something to raise the event

    _eventRaised.WaitOne();
}
```